# HTML Element not visible while embedding form in email?

Tags: html, css, outlook, embed

I have a simple problem. I have created an html file and when i try to embed the html file in my outlook to send it to my client. The elements are not visible. Why? What am i missing. Please guide. Below is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css"> body{background-color: #FFFFFF;font-family: arial;margin: 0;} </style>
<title>TEst</title>
</head>

<body>

<table height="100px;" width="72px;" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">

  <tr>

<section id="form">
<form id="gform"  method="post" action="someAction">
<div id="left-col-forms" style="float: left; width: 330px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px;">



    <fieldset style="width:700px;">
      <label for="name"><b>Name:</b> </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"  style="width:400px;" />
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset style="width:700px;">

    <label for="Phone"><b>Phone:</b> </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="" />
    </fieldset>



<button style="float: left;">Submit</button>
</div>


</form>
</section>
</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some pretty obvious errors that https://validator.w3.org/nu/ would pick up.

Answer (score 1):

Forms in emails are considered a security risk, they typically don't work and depending what email client you are using it may not show at all.

Campaign monitor has a good table you can refer to here:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/forms/

A better solution would be to put the form in a webpage and send them a link to the webpage itself.